# PDAL - pipeline - writers gdal - error: PDAL: All points collinear

Tags: conda, pdal

I have a prepared pipeline which for most files works good. I have one laz file where I have error:
PDAL: All points collinear

What does it mean? Below pipeline in .json

```
    {
        "type":"filters.hag_delaunay"
    },
    {
        "type":"filters.range",
       "limits":[
        "Classification[5:5]"
        ]
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.ferry",
      "dimensions":"HeightAboveGround = Z"
    },
     {
        "type":"writers.gdal",
        "filename":"tile_1703_899_veg.tif",
        "output_type":"max",
        "gdaldriver":"GTiff",
        "window_size":0,
        "resolution":0.5,
        "override_srs":"EPSG:2180"
    
    }
]
```

link to .laz file:
https://mab.to/t/qjImeUcU49F/eu1

Thanks